# How to use Azure API Management portal or API to edit the description string for Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key in the Request Header?

Tags: documentation-generation, azure-api-management

I'm looking for a way to use Azure API Management (either the management portal or an API call) to edit the textual description of the **Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key** Request header fields. This string shows up in auto-generated documentation, but I can't figure out where it's set. So far I've tried looking for the description string for the **Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key** in the swagger file and in the API Management Publisher Portal, but haven't been able to find it.

Here is a screenshot highlighting the field in the generated API documentation that I want to edit:

[image]

Here is the page in the Azure API Management Publisher Portal where I looked for a Request Headers section and couldn't find it:
[image]

Other answers to questions about Azure API Management make me wonder if there's a REST API call to edit this string (if it's not available in the Publisher Portal) but I can't seem to find an active link to API documentation about it.

Comment: I checked the "operation" template in the developer portal. It seems that the particular text is not included in the template directly - it is provided by the backend in the data structure going into the template.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Azure PowerShell for that. Prerequisite is that you're logged in (Login-AzureRmAccount) and selected your subscription (Select-AzureRmSubscription).

```
 $ApiMgmtContext = New-AzureRmApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ServiceName $serviceName

if($ApiMgmtContext)
{
    foreach($apiEntry in (Get-AzureRmApiManagementApi -Context $ApiMgmtContext))
    {
        $api = Get-AzureRmApiManagementApi -Context $ApiMgmtContext -ApiId $apiEntry.ApiId

        Write-Host "setting header for" $api.Name

        $api.SubscriptionKeyHeaderName = "MyApi-Subscription-Key"
        $api | Set-AzureRmApiManagementApi -Context $ApiMgmtContext
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - seems like this can set the header name, to change it from the original `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`, to `MyApi-Subscription-Key`. Is there a way to also set the description associated with this header? For instance if the original description in the generated doc says "Find this key in Cognitive Sevices" and I want to change it say "Find this key in Account Settings"?

Comment: Sorry @DeniseMak, I was not reading your question carefully enough and jumped out with another solution.